# Trouble setting up relationship in Filemaker

Tags: join, filter, relationship, filemaker, self

I'm using Filemaker Pro Advanced 15 on Mac OS 10 El Capitan

I have some filtered portals that I need to turn into portals that are filtered by relationship. I can not figure out how to set this up properly.

I'm trying make a portal that will show me a list of all of the photos that still need to be Touched-Up. When a photo is selected for touchup the customer record is linked with the Photo by a key.

Customer -> Photo

After the photo is emailed out for touchup "EmailSent" goes into Photo::EmailedStatus and if the touchup comes back and needs to be sent out then "Rejected" goes into Photo::ApprovalStatus

I tried to make a self-join relationship between Customers and CustomersJoin and make a cartesian join between the primary fields and then add the rest of the filters using Calculation Fields and Global fields but I can't figure it out because the calculation field needs to be on the left side. I'm not sure if I'm approaching this right can you help me out?

1) What Table should the layout be based on? I have it on Customers is that correct?

2) How can I filter this using this relationship? Am I approaching this right? I want the list to show ALL of the photos where

Customers::Key = Photo:::Key

AND

Photo::EmailedStatus = "Not Emailed"
or
Photo::ApprovalStatus = "Rejected"

Answer (score 1):

Answered here: http://fmforums.com/topic/100789-trouble-setting-up-relationship/?do=findComment&comment=458889

In a nutshell: define a calculation field in the Photos table =

```
If ( EmailedStatus = "Not Emailed" or Photo::ApprovalStatus = "Rejected" ; Key )
```

and use it as the matchfield opposite Customers::Key (in a relationship using another occurrence of the Photos table).